# Unknown Character in 2D Area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to code a tactical RPG on Unity in C#, and to do so, I need to use pathfinding, Dijkstra, nodes edges etc.
I'm trying to convert a 2D Area of char representing my map in a 2D area of nodes with edges, here the map:

[image: map]

The `#` are here to mark the border of the map and dodge an Index Out of Range error.

Here is the code of the project:

```
public Nodes[,] GenerateNodes(TextAsset lvl)
{
    Nodes[,] nodeArray;
    char[,] matrix = GenerateArray(lvl);

    nodeArray = new Nodes[matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1)];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            char type = matrix[row, col];
            if (type != '#' && type != '\n')
            {
                Debug.LogError(type);
                Nodes n = new Nodes(row, col, type);
                nodeArray[row, col] = n;
                findNeighbors(row, col, matrix, nodeArray); //assuming nodes and matrix variables are instance variables
            }
            else
                nodeArray[row, col] = null;
        }
    }
    return nodeArray;
}
public void findNeighbors(int row, int col, char[,] matrix, Nodes[,] nodeArray)
{
    for (int r = -1; r <= 1; r++)
    {
        for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
        {
            Debug.LogError(row);
            Debug.LogError(col);
            if (matrix[row + r, col + c] != '#')
            {
                nodeArray[row, col].addEdges(nodeArray[row + r, col + c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `GenerateArray()` method is working; I was using that before.  The problem comes from the `findNeighbors()`.  I have this error:

> Array Out of range at the row 0 and the columns 19

The problem is I just have some `#` here, and it isn't even supposed to be here.  I tried to print that char and it prints nothing, so I tried to rewrite the line, suppress the `\n` etc, and I still get nothing.

Comment: Are the line endings of the sample file just "\n"? Or are they "\r\n"?

Comment: I'm on windows, good guess, it was that damn \r, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I counted, there is 18 columns and you are trying to access column 19 and of course it will throw this exception.

You should put an if like this on the second for of your findneighbors:

```
if(row == 0 && r == -1)
  continue;
if(col == matrix.GetLength(1) && c == 1)
  continue;
```

Maybe you can find a better way to do what Im telling you to, but keep in mind if you don't avoid accessing an index of the array that doesn't exists you will keep getting this error.

Edit.
According to our fellow @yes, there are 19 cols and not 18 as I wrongly counted. The solution I provided is still valid altough :D

Comment: no its 19 cols, thats ok, but since arrays are zero indexed an index of 19 ofc is out of range. the problem arises exactly where you state though. its the neighbors on the edges. there is no col + 1 for the leftmost col.